# How do I troubleshoot an issue between Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, youtube, embed

```
<iframe width="853" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/BcNkL6irfUQ?version=3&" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

When I embed the above and view it in Chrome, it shows up fine.  However when I view the same code in Firefox, it asks me to download a file and doesn't display the embedded video.  Any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that flash is not installed or enabled in your firefox browser.

View http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html to see if flash is working properly in firefox